# During his fight with Winter was Qrow going easy and why if so?

Tags: rwby

When Qrow was fighting Winter, he swung his sword and cut the pole at one point, then he missed again when he stabbed the wood or whatever you call it and when shooting at her he missed. Some say he was trying to kill her but his semblance is misfortune: if he wanted her dead, it should not have been hard. So was he going easy on her, and if so for what reason?

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that they were aquainted before it's also clear that when fighting both were holding back as proved when Winter simply hit Qrow in the face but didn't cut him.

Now these two may not get along too well, but they're not real enemies so no, Qrow wasn't trying to kill her. Just back her off because she did strike first (though he provoked her). She could've ignored him and walked away but she chose to attack him.

She wasn't going to kill him, just teach him respect. But these two would help the other if there was a real enemy on the attack. In short they're actually allies, they're just mad at each other for some reason.

By the way it's shown later in the same episode that Winter doesn't like him being drunk, so that explains part of it.

Comment: Also I am sure Winter will return some time so let's just wait for Rooster Teeth to give us the answer! ;)

Answer (score 2):

He was going easy on her and it's because he didn't want to really hurt her. It's been assumed by fans that they don't like each other, but there's really no evidence that he has that big of a problem with her. It's more that he is upset at her for some reason, but he actually criticized James Ironwood more and she didn't like that or the fact that he was purposely provokingly her, so she attacked in anger.

But we see that she does hold herself back a bit because she hits him, but she doesn't cut him and then runs a lot of the time and when she was really fighting she didn't inflict any real damage on him.

The truth is the two are on the same side and Qrow wasn't going to hurt her, just defend himself cause she struck first, but she wasn't trying to severally hurt him. Also, she was angry at the fact that he was drunk as well.